# Azure: How to check storage account exists in Azure with Get-AzureStorageAccount

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I am building a power shell script to automate the setup of a website environment in Azure. This web uses an account storage. I want to the script not to create the account storage if exists.

I thought that using `Get-AzureStorageAccount` this way may work but it does not:

```
Write-Verbose "[Start] creating $Name storage account $Location location"

$storageAcct = Get-AzureStorageAccount –StorageAccountName $Name
if (!$storageAcct)
{   
    $storageAcct = New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $Name -Location $Location -Verbose
    if ($storageAcct)
    {
        Write-Verbose "[Finish] creating $Name storage account in $Location location"
    }
    else
    {
        throw "Failed to create a Windows Azure storage account. Failure in New-AzureStorage.ps1"
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Verbose "$Name storage account in $Location location already exists, skipping creation"
}
```

The issue is I don't know how to handle the return of `Get-AzureStorageAccount`.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you mean by ".. don't know how to handle the return of `Get-AzureStorageAccount`.`? What is happening and what do you want to happen?

Comment: If `Get-AzureStorageAccount` does not return an storage account with the name I provide then create the storage account, otherwise skip the step.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would suggest using the Test-AzureName cmdlet to determine if it exists.  So, something like this.

```
if (!(Test-AzureName -Storage $Name))
{  
    Write-Host "Creating Storage Account $Name"
    New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $Name -Location $Location 
}
```

You can use Test-AzureName for other services too, such as Cloud Services, WebSites, and ServiceBus.  It returns True if it exists, False otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

```
Get-AzureRmStorageAccountNameAvailability -Name "accountname"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```powershell
$Name = "myStorageAccount"
$Location = "myLocation"

Write-Host "[Start] creating $Name storage account $Location location"
try{
    Get-AzureStorageAccount –StorageAccountName $Name -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
    Write-Host "$Name storage account in $Location location already exists, skipping creation"
    }
catch{
    Write-Host "[Finish] creating $Name storage account in $Location location"
    New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $Name -Location $Location -Verbose      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the current Az module for PowerShell Version 7, the [Get-AzStorageAccountNameAvailability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageaccountnameavailability?view=azps-6.0.0) cmdlet might offer a more efficient solution as it was designed specifically for this task. Here is an example:

```
# ... declare variables and specify values ...

$checkNameAvail = (Get-AzStorageAccountNameAvailability -Name $storageAccountName) | `
Select-Object NameAvailable

if ($checkNameAvail.NameAvailable) 
{
  Write-Host 'Account name available! Please wait while your resource is being created'

  # Create account. Variables used in this example would have been declared earlier in the script.
  $storageAccount = (New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -AccountName $storageAccountName `
    -Location $location `
    -SkuName $skuType `
    -AllowBlobPublicAccess $false -EnableHttpsTrafficOnly $true)
# ... 
}
else 
{
  # This section of the script executes if the name is not available
  Write-Host "The name <$storageAccountName> is not available. Suggest a new globally unique name!"
}
```

The condition above will return `False`, and execute the `else` statement because the boolean value returned by the cmdlet is in `[0]` as shown in the PowerShell command-line test below. The availability information (boolean) can thus be stripped from the object returned by the cmdlet and (as in this example) used as a condition in the rest of the script.

```
PS C:\> Get-AzStorageAccountNameAvailability -Name testaccount1

NameAvailable        Reason Message
-------------        ------ -------
        False AlreadyExists The storage account named testaccount1 is already taken.
```

Comment: In 2024, this is the correct answer: we should be using Az module for PowerShell Version 7

Answer (score 1):

Test-AzureName didn't work with our build agents and we already had a try/catch in code so a second one would require building it out as a function. I opted for that standard get and check if null, use -ErrorAction Ignore to stop it throwing an exception

```
# Check for storage account and create if not found    
$StorageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -Name $StorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $StorageAccountRG -ErrorAction Ignore
if ($StorageAccount -eq $null)  
{    
    New-AzureRmStorageAccount -Location "West Europe" -Name $StorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $StorageAccountRG -SkuName Standard_LRS -Kind Storage     
    $StorageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -Name $StorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $StorageAccountRG   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Rick Rainey's solution works if you're logged in using `Add-AzureAccount`. However, Azure and powershell have a conflicting and confusing suite of login accounts (Windows Live versus AD) and login mechanisms (Classic: `Add-AzureAccount`; Resource manager: `Login-AzureRmAccount`). Some Azure powershell cmdlets require a specific login; further, some require a specific account type!

To clear through this thicket of complicated, undocumented, and confusing permission issues, we always use an AD account, logging in via `Login-AzureRmAccount`. We also use Azure resource manager (ARM) resources and cmdlets, following Microsoft's movement to ARM as its recommended and strategic approach. However, @RIck's solution is one which the ARM login doesn't work with. :-( So you need another approach, which is @Darren's (for storage). However, for a generic replacement for `Test-AzureName` I'd suggest `Find-AzureRmResource`.  In the case of storage

```
$StorageObject = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $storageName}        
if  ( !$StorageObject ) {
    $storageLocation = (Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup).Location
    $storageType = "Standard_LRS"
    New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup  -Name $storageName -Location $storageLocation -Type $storageType
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the latest Powershell module [Az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.3.0).

```
if ($(Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName) -eq $null)
{
    # does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the error variable

```
Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName 'RG-QA-TEST' -Name 'staccountfor12334ff' -ErrorVariable ev1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($ev1) {
    Write-Host "-------------------------- Creating OEM Storage"
    //create storage account
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please consider to put your code in a code environment next time :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had this challenge when setting up **Azure storage accounts** for Static website hosting using **Powershell** in **Octopus Deploy**.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Using the [Az module for Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-5.7.0) I did the following:

```
# Define Variables
$RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME = my-resource-group
$LOCATION = northeurope
$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = myapplication
$SKU_NAME = Standard_GRS
$STORAGE_KIND = StorageV2

# Check Storage Account and Create if not Found
$STORAGE_ACCOUNT = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME -Name $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME -ErrorAction Ignore

if ($STORAGE_ACCOUNT -eq $null)  {    
    Write-Host 'Creating storage account'
    New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME -AccountName $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME -Location $LOCATION -SkuName $SKU_NAME -Kind $STORAGE_KIND
    Write-Host "$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME storage account successfully created"
}
else {
    Write-Host "$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME storage account already exists"
}
```

**Note**:

`-ErrorAction Ignore` - This ignores the exception that would arise if the storage account does not exist
`Write-Host " "` - Double quotes were used to allow for string interpolation since we are connecting strings and variables.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**